# convertir List<Document> a json

Tags: java, json, mongodb

tengo un problema no se como convertir el `List<document>` a json :

```
    public static List<Document> d() {
            conexion c = new conexion();
            List<Document> resultados = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Document cur : c.table.find()){
                resultados.add(cur);
            }      
            return resultados;
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hay una forma mas fácil según la documentación de mongo [aqui](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/getting-started/quick-start/)

```
 public static List<String> d() {
        conexion c = new conexion();
        List<String> resultados = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Document cur : c.table.find()){
            resultados.add(cur.toJson());
//contiene un error en la sintaxis  System.out.println("toda la collection"+.find());
        }      
        return resultados;
    }
```

así directamente etas obteniendo una lista completa de json´s para que lo utilices, con el metodo `toJson()` conviertes los objetos del table en json. al final lo que obtienes es una cadena ("`String`") con formato *json*

como algo adicional [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39923406/bson-document-to-json-in-java) hay una pregunta similar en ingles

Comment: Document  tiene un método toJson() ???

Comment: Como puedes imprimir la colección con .find()?

Comment: se pueden transformar a un objeto de mongo DbObject , o en este caso docuemnt que es mas facil de utilizar a mi parecer aunque para este caso hay que implementar un patron iterator para recorrer la el resultado del .find()

DBcursor almacena el resultado 
Dbcursro cur = table.find()
y con el patron iterator se utiliza el cur 
`while(cur.hasNext()){
   DBObject caht = cur.next();
}`

Comment: ¿? 0_o a ok, creo que solo con System.out.println( c.table.find())

Comment: El  `.find();` solo mostraría el objeto que tiene por dentro el iterator pero no los datos, ya había intentado algo así y si es necesario el recorrerlo

Answer (score 0):

Para convertir un Document a Json, se usa el método [toJson()](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/org/bson/Document.html#toJson--) que obtiene una representación en Json de Document

Para obtener todas las tablas del documento se realiza de esta forma:

```
    List<String> resultados = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Document cur : c.table.find()){
        resultados.add(cur.toJson());
    }
```

También puedes usar una BasicDBList para guardarlo y obtener el Json de toda la colección mediante `JSON.serialize()`:

```
   MongoCursor<Document> iterator = c.table.find().iterator();

    BasicDBList list = new BasicDBList();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Document doc = iterator.next();
        list.add(doc);
    }
    System.out.println(JSON.serialize(list));
```